# How do you log responses with oauth2 gem?

Tags: logging, oauth-2.0, rubygems, response

I see that oauth2 uses Faraday to handle requests and response which has support for logging to stdout. How do you enable that option with the [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set ENV variable `OAUTH_DEBUG=true`